# How I keep elements of ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I expect this program to print this result:

```
[john, smith, 85]

[michol, smith, 65]

[benz, red, 90]
```

but output of this program is:

```
[]

[]

[]
```

please help me to correction that.

```
package javaapplication12;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class JavaApplication12 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] l=new String[3];
        l[0]="benz black 85";
        l[1]="BMW red 56";
        l[2]="benz red 90";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ss = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
                String[] part=l[j].split(" ");
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                    s.add(part[i]);
                ss.add(s);
                s.clear();
        }
        System.out.println(ss.get(0));
        System.out.println(ss.get(1));
        System.out.println(ss.get(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should know that Java works with object references which are passed by value.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the same `ArrayList<String> s` to add the data of `part[]`, then add it into `ss` and clearing it. In the  end, it's like you add the same empty `ArrayList<String>` to `ss`.

Just declare and initialize `ArrayList<String> s` inside the first `for` loop. This will create a new `ArraList<String>` instance per iteration. Also, there's no need to clear the list.

The code should look like this (commented lines that you should remove):

```
//ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] part=l[j].split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        s.add(part[i]);
    ss.add(s);
    //s.clear();
}
```